# View Image file from cache in gallery android

Tags: java, android, image, caching, gallery

I want to view cached image into gallery. I've downloaded a `Bitmap` and cached in a temp file

```
File cacheFile = File.createTempFile("Image", "jpg", context.getCacheDir());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

then I used an intent to view it in gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(cacheFile ), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

I got the following exception

```
04-12 10:42:56.790 2281-2281/system:ui E/StrictMode: file:// Uri exposed through Intent.getData()
    java.lang.Throwable: file:// Uri exposed through Intent.getData()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1580)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2339)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:7012)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1418)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onIntentSelected(ResolverActivity.java:371)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.startSelected(ResolverActivity.java:285)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onButtonClick(ResolverActivity.java:278)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 10:42:56.900 2714-10842/com.android.gallery E/UriImage: got exception decoding bitmap 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:173)
    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-12 10:42:56.900 2714-10842/com.android.gallery E/UriImage: got exception decoding bitmap 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:204)
    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

any suggestions?
**Update**
Somehow I don't get an exception now, but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried changing the suffix as I suggested in my answer? If it doesn't throw an exception now, what happens instead?

Comment: @SteffenB yeah, but still the same problem.

Comment: Could it be that the gallery doesn't have read access to the file since it's a temporary file created by your app and not the gallery app itself? (I suggest you to test this using a public dir instead of the system temp)

Comment: @SteffenB Sure it works with external storage, I just wanted to try it with cache. Maybe like you said, it can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix should be `.jpg` or `.jpeg` instead of just `jpg`

> suffix - The suffix string to be used in generating the file's name; may be null, in which case the suffix ".tmp" will be used

**EDIT**

The gallery won't be able to access the path since it's the tmp dir of your app. You must place the picture outside (external storage maybe?) so the gallery can access it.

Comment: It didn't work, I've even tried different extensions with different bitmaps but still the same